# check for message content in discord for a specific word in discord.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I'm creating a grammar bot in discord.py. however, I can't find anything on how to check a specific word in a message. I know how to check what the message starts with but I can't find a fix to the former problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's pretty easy, you can use the following code:

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if "word" in message.content:
          print("Something")
          #or
          await message.channel.send("Something")
    await client.process_commands(message)
```

That's pretty much it.

Comment: thanks a lot. I'm really new to discord bots so I wasn't sure.

Comment: No problem I was in your point 2 months ago, good luck!

Answer (score 0):

So you have message content with `message.content` you need to do `message.content.split()` which gets all the words. Then you can compare each word to what you want.